# Im trying to write a function to get an average out of a table in python but I get an error saying 'List index out of range'

Tags: python, average

Im trying to make a function in python to find an average out of a table.
In `number_table` there are 4 items so I put the count to 4. The error says : `sum += table[i] IndexError: list index out of range`.

Here is the code :

```
number_table = [1, 3, 5, 100]

def average(table, count):
    sum = 0
    for i in table:
        sum += table[i]

    return sum / count

print(average(number_table, 4))
```

Comment: `for i in table` means for each *item*, not index. `i` is a value from the list, so it will fail on the 3rd iteration since it calls `table[5]`. Also use `len(table)` to get the length automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best pythonic and efficient ways:

```
def average(table):
    return sum(table)/len(table)
```

or

```
from statistics import mean


def average(table):
    return statistics.mean(table)
```

Comment: Since when is `mean()` a built-in?

Comment: Yes you are right, I did this mistake because I have been using it a lot for myself and completely forgot it was not built-in.

Comment: Appreciate the fix :) +1

Answer (score 2):

using:

```
for i in table:
```

returns the elements in the table. so if you access table[i] will go out of range in third iterations, since third element is 5 and your list has 4 elements.

what you are looking for is

```
number_table = [1, 3, 5, 100]

def average(table):
    table_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(table)):
        table_sum += table[i]

    return table_sum / len(table)

print(average(number_table))
```

note that i changed the variable *sum* to *table_sum*, because sum is a python function and you are overriding it (works but dangerous.....)

then you do not need the count, because you can divide by the length of the table which can be obtained using *len(table)*

Comment: And why not do it the Pythonic way, `for i in table: table_sum += i`?

Comment: because I am sure that duckquy puf is learning python, so it is better to use indexes so that you learn them. but you are right too :) very pythonista way. Personally I am a fan of indexes.

Comment: If you care about only the values, iterate over the values. If you care about indices, you can do that if you only intend on mutating. If both are important, use `enumerate()`. In this case, especially since it's about learning Python, it is recommended to actually do it the Pythonic way. Emulating the style of a different language is just kind of questionable...

Comment: I agree, I tried to stick to the question context. but if we want to be very precise then the answer of [B Remmelzwaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17200348/b-remmelzwaal) is the cleanest one. Thanks for your constructive comments, If duckquy reads them I am sure that he will become a better py programmer.

Comment: It's always useful to have multiple methods in your toolbox to approach a problem, and to know what differences they have. I also appreciate the comment on not shadowing built-ins which can save a lot of headaches down the road :)

Comment: shhh dont tell him, he will leran by doing :D p.s how can I mark your responses as useful? I cant because I am new here and I still have very few points :/ lets hope somebody votes or accept my answers. maybe you can comment [RifloSnake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20959773/riflosnake) answer because mean() does not exist. at least in python 3.9. Cheers and have a good one

Comment: You'll gain those privileges once you acquire enough points, which you should be able to find on your profile.

Comment: you are welcome, but also consider the B Remmelzwaal answer because if you read these comments you will see why experienced python developers rather to use *out of the box* methods.

Answer (score 2):

With all the comments suggesting what to do, this is what you *should* be doing:

```py
number_table = [1, 3, 5, 100]

print(sum(number_table)/len(number_table))
```

`sum()` is a built-in function in Python which takes an iterable to do summations on. `len()` is another built-in function that returns the length of an object (in this case the number of elements in the list), so you don't have to hard-code this value which comes in handy when adding more values to the table. You should make use of them when possible, as it gives shorter and more readable code.

Comment: thanks theirs also works btw but this is more efficient i see

Comment: Just put the methods you've seen in your toolbox and use them in your future endeavours :)

Comment: how do you find the toolbox?

Comment: It's a metaphorical toolbox haha, I just mean you can remember them and use them in later projects :)